# Zsh don't wait for prompt

Tags: bash, delay, prompt, weather

I have some prompt set in oh-my-zsh theme which include some 'curl/wget' commands which obtain weather status. But every time I start the shell, prompt just waiting like 9-10 seconds before welcome me. What I'd like to do is to be able to set 'dynamic' prompt: default prompt without weather shows up momentarily when I start shell, then in 'background' weather is obtained and added to prompt (for example, when some command was executed and another one prompt shown). How can I do that?

UPDATE: I decided to go with cron job which will fetch weather simply every 5 minutes and then I can `cat` it not only to zsh prompt, but to any system part I want (for example, to WM statusbar). Although for people who are looking for answer on my exact question I'd recommend to try something like James Andrews proposed.

Answer (score 2):

In your `.zshrc` file you could set

```
# How long to wait before calling TRAPALRM()
TMOUT=300

# called when TMOUT reaches 0
TRAPALRM()
{
    # run this command in the background so my shell resets
    {
        export WEATHER=$(...)
    }&!
}
```

And your prompt could use the `$WEATHER` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas:

1. use the curl `--max-time` option to limit the damage.
2. have a cron job that runs every 5 minutes or so, fetch and write the weather to a file, your prompt can read the file.

Comment: Wow, I really stupid not to thought about it earlier! (cron job) This isn't actually related to the topic theme, but this is perfect solution. I can set cron to fetch weather each 5 minutes into /tmp/somefile and then simply cat it not only to zsh prompt, but to my WM statusbar and any other thing in system. Great!